# Flask+Sqlite: Strings that are integers return as type int?

Tags: python, string, sqlite, int, flask

When I store a content with an integer value as a string, when I retrive it it's suddenly an int.

So here is what I'm seeing: I store with this

```
db = get_db()
hello = escape(str(request.form['name'])).striptags()
what = escape(str(request.form['content'])).striptags()
db.execute('''insert into entry (
title, content, score, approved, pub_date) values (?, ?, 0, 0,?)''',
[hello,what,int(time.time())])
raise Exception('what')
db.commit()
```

And when I submit from the page, say `form['name']='1'` and `form['content']='2'`, at the `Exception`, `hello==u'1'` and `content==u'2'`. This is all good so far. Then I store in the `DB`, but when I go to retrieve, suddenly the entries are type `int` `1` and `2`. Everything goes correctly for any other string, say `"lorem ispum"`.

In my `sql schema`, `title` and `content` are both type `string`. What's going on?

Comment: How do you detect that they are ints and not strings?

Comment: I'm getting an error in which a function doesn't work on type "int". Also, I open the Flask console by raising an error and check what comes back from the query and it is indeed an int.

Comment: Still don't know the answer, BUT I just put in workaround by casting the query results to strings before supplying them to the template.

Comment: Okay. Yes this is strange behavior and should happen only if the database column type is INT/NUMERIC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in SQLite using any column type does not guarantee that this column will be permitted to store only value of this type - it can still store value of any type.

I think what is happening in your case is that your column has INTEGER or NUMERIC affinity, and in this case SQLite will normally store value of INTEGER type. However, if you try to store data that cannot be cast to INTEGER losslessly, SQLite will automatically convert it to TEXT. (Or, your column may be of TEXT affinity, but Python has somehow forced this field to store it as INTEGER if it looks like integer).

You can read more about this in [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) - scroll to *2.0 Type Affinity*.

Comment: You're right! "string" isn't recognized by SQLite at all, so I guess it defaulted to NUMERIC affinity. I changed my schema to "text" and now it exhibits the correct behavior. Thanks!